# unordered_map judge if the key is in the map

Tags: c++, g++, linked-list, unordered-map

I tried this piece of code

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <utility>
 #include <vector>
 #include <unordered_map>
 #include <stdexcept>

 using namespace std;

 int main() {
    unordered_map<int,int> parent_map;
    try {
        int a = parent_map[0];
        cout<<a<<endl;

    } catch (out_of_range oe) {
        cout<<"out of range"<<endl;
    }

    return 0;

 }
```

I think the out of range exception should be caught. However, the output is

```
0
```

I am confused. I remember I got this working before.

Answer (score 5):

`operator[]` doesn't throw, you want to try [std::unordered_map::at](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/at)

```
int a = parent_map.at(0);
```

Also `operator[]` will **insert an element if key is not found.**

And you want to capture exception by reference

```
catch (const out_of_range &oe) {
   cout<<"out of range: " << oe.what() <<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int a = parent_map[0];
```

Is assigning a new entry to the map with key `0`, and default value `0`.

You're essentially doing this:

```
parent_map[0] = int();
```

What you want to do is `find()` the key in the map, and check it's not the **end** of the container.

```
if(parent_map.find(0) != parent_map.end())
{
  // Element exists.
}
```

Comment: shouldn't assignment be parent_map[0] = a?

Comment: @AlfredZhong: it evaluates "parent_map[0]" as an expression, and its meaning is to return a reference to the element with index 0 in the map, creating it if it doesn't exist. This behaviour is necessary to allow the convenient notation `parent_map[0] = a`: the left hand side - `parent_map[0]` - is evaluated as an expression before the assignment is done. It can also be convenient, as in `while (file >> word) ++word_count[word];` which concisely creates a count of all distinct words in the input, but sometimes it's confusing as you've seen. Pros and cons.